# How to join paragraph in HTML without removing <p> tag

Tags: html, css

I have created code to print some data.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>The p element</h1>

<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

This give me a result below:

```
The p element
This is a paragraph.

This is a paragraph.

This is a paragraph.
```

But what i want to do is to join this three lines without removing `<p>` tag.

My expected result is:

```
The p element
This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph.
```

Comment: Add css `p {margin-bottom: 0, display: inline-block}`

Comment: Do you need this exact structure? With a slight change, wrapping your three `p` elements you can achieve this easily.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned above, changing a bit the structure should do the trick. Just wrap your three `p` elements into a `div` and use `flexbox`.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<h1>The p element</h1>

<div class="wrapper">
    <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
    <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
    <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This looks very weird on small screens. You get basically `This is a This is a This is a paragraph paragraph paragraph`

Comment: I was also facing similar problem. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

You can change css like this :

```
p {
    display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

THere is no need to add to the DOM in order to achieve this, and to keep your semantics as they are you probably shouldn't.

Instead CSS can be used to make the p elements display inline-block.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    p {
      display: inline-block;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <h1>The p element</h1>

  <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
  <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
  <p>This is a paragraph.</p>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add **display:inline** for **p** tag:

```css
p {
display: inline
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>The p element</h1>

    <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
    <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
    <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `display: flex` and `flex-direction: row` , optionaly can include `gap` :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>The p element</title>
    <style>
        .wrapper {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            gap: 4px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>The p element</h1>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
        <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
        <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[See details here](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox)